# how to show the picture to repeat if its empty?

Tags: php, if-statement

Im trying to create this thing that if its get nothing from a array it would bring up a default picture but its not working out the way i want it to. It using every array but i want to separate each away.

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `im_album` WHERE username = '".$user_data['username']."'  ");
$d_name = array();
$d_amount = array();
$d_cover = array();
while(($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    $d_name[] = $row['name'];

    $d_mode[] = $row['mode'];
    $d_amount[] = $row['amount'];
    $d_cover[]= $row['cover'];
 }
$p_cover = implode($d_cover) ;
  if ( $p_cover == "") {
  $p_cover = "cpages/img/default_pic.jpg";
  }
  else
  {
  $p_cover= "userdata/".$user_data['username']."/profilepic/".$p_cover;
  }
<img  style="margin:2pt" src="<?php echo $p_cover ?>"  height="250" width="200"  />
```

Comment: What kind of data is in `$d_cover`? You're imploding them together with no separator, so all array elements just get concatenated together.

Comment: a image .jpg,, How do i separate it?

Comment: i also want it to show the default image if its empty the data.

Comment: Are you expecting multiple rows back from the query with different images? Your code seems to imply you would get only one since you are placing `$p_cover` into a string.

Comment: yes sir. do you know how can i fix that cause i don't use array that often so im like new to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `im_album` WHERE username = '".$user_data['username']."'  ");
while ($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $d_name = $row['name'];
  $d_mode = $row['mode'];
  $d_amount = $row['amount'];
  $d_cover = $row['cover'];
  if ( $d_cover == "") {
  $p_cover = "cpages/img/default_pic.jpg";
  }
  else
  {
  $p_cover= "userdata/".$user_data['username']."/profilepic/".$d_cover;
  }
  echo '<img  style="margin:2pt" src="'.$p_cover.'"  height="250" width="200"  />';
}
```

Comment: its going to be more than one row because it would be getting from mysql, like this [link](http://www.deviantart.com/),, you see how their pictures are all neat in rows and each row has 4 pictures than it creates a new column, but what im trying to do here is if mysql is empty the default picture would pop up for each album, i hope that makes since

Comment: See the updated answer. I've put back the while-loop, but I display the image for each album within the loop.

Comment: wooww!!  your amazing i been searching and asking people how to do that. now im gonna try to understand what you did their

Comment: i see what you did their, it makes since , thanks soo much for your help :D